# Simple oracle insert

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am trying to simply insert some information to a table in Oracle using Forms. Sometimes the insert statement works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm just not experienced enough with Oracle to understand what's not working. Here's the code:

```
PROCEDURE create_account IS
temp_name varchar2(30);
temp_street varchar2(30);
temp_zip number(5);
temp_phone varchar2(30);
temp_login passuse.login%type;
temp_pass varchar2(30);
temp_total number(4);
temp_lgn passuse.lgn%type;
cursor num_cursor is
    select MAX(ano)
    from accounts;
cursor lgn_cursor is
    select MAX(lgn)
    from passuse;
BEGIN
temp_name:= Get_Item_Property('ACCOUNTS.A_NAME', database_value);
temp_street:= Get_Item_Property('ACCOUNTS.STREET', database_value);
temp_zip:= Get_Item_Property('ACCOUNTS.ZIP', database_value);
temp_phone:= Get_Item_Property('ACCOUNTS.STREET', database_value);
temp_login:= Get_Item_Property('PASSUSE.LOGIN', database_value);
temp_pass:= Get_Item_Property('PASSUSE.PASS', database_value);

open num_cursor;
fetch num_cursor into temp_total;

open lgn_cursor;
fetch lgn_cursor into temp_lgn;


if(lgn_cursor%found) then
    if(num_cursor%found) then
                    temp_lgn := temp_lgn + 20;
                    --the trouble maker..
                    INSERT INTO passuse (lgn, a_type, login, pass)
                    VALUES (temp_lgn, 1, temp_login, temp_pass);
                    temp_total := temp_total+1;
                    INSERT INTO accounts(ano,lgn,a_name,street,zip,phone)
                    VALUES (temp_total,temp_lgn,temp_name,temp_street,temp_zip,temp_phone);
    end if;
end if;
close lgn_cursor;
close num_cursor;
commit;

END;
```

Comment: What exception do you get when it fails?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean - does it just not insert something you're expecting, or do you get an error? Can you run it stand-alone and debug the values you're trying to insert (e.g. `dbms_output` statements)?

Comment: You should consider using SEQUENCEs for ano & lgn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Mikpa's comment - it certainly appears that getting the values for ACCOUNTS.ANO and PASSUSE.LGN from sequences would be a good idea.  Populating these fields automatically by using a trigger would also be helpful.  Something like the following:

```
-- Note that the following is intended as a demo.  When executing these statements
-- you'll probably have to modify them for your particular circumstances.

SELECT MAX(ANO) INTO nMax_ano FROM ACCOUNTS;
SELECT MAX(LGN) INTO nMax_lgn FROM PASSUSE;

CREATE SEQUENCE ACCOUNTS_SEQ START WITH nMax_ano+1;
CREATE SEQUENCE PASSUSE_SEQ START WITH nMax_lgn+1;

CREATE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.ANO
    FROM DUAL;
END ACCOUNTS_BI;

CREATE TRIGGER PASSUSE_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON PASSUSE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT PASSUSE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.LGN
    FROM DUAL;
END PASSUSE_BI;
```

Having done the above you can now write your inserts into these tables as

```
INSERT INTO passuse (a_type, login, pass)           
  VALUES (1, temp_login, temp_pass)
RETURNING LGN INTO temp_lgn;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO accounts(lgn, a_name, street, zip, phone)           
  VALUES (temp_lgn, temp_name, temp_street, temp_zip, temp_phone);
```

Note that in the both statements the key values (PASSUSE.LGN and ACCOUNTS.ANO) are not mentioned in the field list as the new triggers should take care of filling them in correctly.  Also note that when inserting into PASSUSE the RETURNING clause is used to get back the new value for LGN so it can be used in the insert into the ACCOUNTS table.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: so where in relation to my code would I put this stuff? Sorry, I'm completely new to oracle, and my teacher's not helping much.

Comment: to elaborate, this is a procedure which is called up by a WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger

Comment: Triggers and sequences are objects which exist in the database separately from your code.  They just sit out there "in the database" waiting to be used.  To create them you'd use something like SQL*Plus (Oracle's command line tool for executing SQL).  Or you could use one of the GUI tools such as PL/SQL Developer, Toad, or Oracle's SQL Developer.